# How query all objects that are associated to this or that?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 models, `User`, `House`, and `Car`. How can I find all Users that own a house or a car with a single query? Here is how my models are setup, and below is what I'm currently doing to achieve the same result.

```
class User
  has_many :houses
  has_many :cars
end

class House
  belongs_to :user
end

class Car
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Attempt:

```
User.where(id: House.all.pluck(:user_id) + Car.all.pluck(:user_id)).distinct
```

Unfortunately this has to do 3 queries, one to get all the House user_ids, another for the Car user_ids, and then a final one to get the Users. Is there a creative way to use joins to find all users that have a house or a car?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
User.left_outer_joins(:houses, :cars)
    .select("users.id, count(houses.id), count(cars.id)")
    .group("users.id")
    .having("count(houses.id) > 0 OR count(cars.id) > 0")
```

Comment: That appears to only return users that have both a house and a car, not either or. Thanks though!

Comment: Can you use left_outer_joins instead?

Comment: It looks like `left_outer_joins` is returning all of the users, regardless of if they have a house or a car.

Comment: and then append `.having("count(houses.id) > 0 OR  count(cars.id) > 0")`

Comment: That worked! I was not familiar with `#having`. Can you please update your answer?

Comment: I didn't need the `.select` portion, seemed to work with just `left_outer_joins`, `group`, and `having`